# Find the user of a crashing process

Tags: debian, shell, terminal, process, services

When I run `service mongod start`, a certain process will run and crash almost instantly causing the service to fail. I suspect this issue to be that the process doesn't run as the correct user.

The logs for that service where not helpful at all unfortunately.

So I would like to find out under which user that process will be created.

`ps aux` doesn't work because the process crashes too quickly.

Can I somehow log all processes that are going to crash into a file including the user name or something like that?

I'm on Debian Wheezy inside of a Docker container.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to wrap `strace` around the startup process, which entails either wrapping `systemd` itself, or instead to alter the `mongod.service` to call an appropriate `strace` wrapper that in turn then starts up `mongod`. Pros: no kernel modules necessary. Cons: will slow things down, fiddly edits to the `mongod` service file (remember to undo them...), or could interfere with the problem in unknown ways.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec strace -ff -o /root/lookatthese -e trace=process /mongodb/startup/command/here
```

Another way would be to use `sysdig` or `SystemTap` which do require kernel modules but offer more efficient logging of what is going on without needing to insert `strace` between the usual steps:

```
# sysdig 'evt.type = execve'
...
```

Would show all `execve` calls while you then run the usual startup command; to include the user use something like

```
# sysdig -p \
  '%evt.time %proc.name[%proc.pid] uid=%user.uid ppid=%proc.ppid %proc.exeline' \
  'evt.type = execve'
```

or one could instead capture more data (depending on how busy the system is) and analyze that output file in detail.